# Why does printing from Excel to pdf not maintain the size/border of the original Excel doc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print from Excel to pdf - I've followed advice I've seen online and the print preview looks fine. The printed pdf on the other hand looks totally different, with a large white border. Pictures below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2SSB.jpg

I've also tried using VBA, as follows:

`ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=x1TypePDF,  OpenAfterPublish:=True`

Would appreciate any advice at all here. Thanks

Comment: Excel offers native support for saving as .PDF. Why not using that functionality?

Comment: @LPChip printing and saving to pdf results in the same problem. The output is identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft *Print to PDF* has a [number of settings in the print dialog](https://www.howtogeek.com/666835/how-to-print-to-pdf-on-windows-10/), such as paper size (e.g., 8.5x11 inch, A3 or A4), number of sheets per page (e.g., one can print 1, 2 or even 6 spreadsheets on on piece of paper), whether to scale to page, or not, etc. Your **default** settings likely are not correct for the paper you use.

To set the *default* printer setup,

[image: MS Print to PDF defaults]

- Open the *Devices and Printers* dialog.
- Select *Microsoft Print to PDF*.
- Right-click, and set *Printing preferences*, including *Advanced*, appropriately.
- Right-click  and set *Printing properties* appropriately.

Next time you use PDF printing, the new defaults should work.

Comment: This worked! The default print output was set to "letter" where it should have been A4. Thank you, this has been bugging me for a while.